# How to increase image size without scale image with php

Tags: php, image, webp

I want to change `.webp` image width or height to a higher value, and add some transparent area to the image.

For example, imagine I have a `width:512*height:312` `webp` image, I need two steps:

1- Add `512*200` transparent area to my image.

2- Transform my image to the center of the new image.

OR

1- Add `512*100` transparent area to the top of my image.

2- Add `512*100` transparent area to the bottom of my image.

The final result I want, a `512*512` `.webp` image without any scale on my original image.

How can I do this with the PHP language?

Comment: [GD library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) contains some methods for manipulating images. But you truly have to decide wheter you want to try to do this on the server or client-side, i.e. please remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: I want do this on server side.

Comment: GD is a PHP library, as well as Imagick introduced in Tns' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [Imagick](https://phpimagick.com/Tutorial/edgeExtend) extension.